# Get the Path Image of Camera Uri in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm confused why I'm getting an inaccurate path, or I guess this is the correct path, but the thing is I want to get the `.jpg file` taken from the camera and I want to display it using URI `ImageVIEW` but if I used this path it's getting me an error since there's no specific format of the image which is `.jpg/png something.` it helpful for me if someone's have an idea.

*I have this path but not in the `.jpg/png` format*

```
/external/images/media/174131
```

*Camera when getting path*

```
 Uri image_uri;
 private void pickCamera() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, " NewPic");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image to Text");
    image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);

    Log.d(TAG,"Get the path below");
    Log.d(TAG,image_uri.getPath());
}
```

*Display to the ImageView*

```
 ImageView mPreviewIv = findViewById(R.id.Scannedimage);

 String resultUri = extras.getString("CashCardImage"); //the result is /external/images/media/174131
 Uri myUri = Uri.parse(resultUri);
 mPreviewIv.setImageURI(myUri);
```

*I passed the value path to another activity*

```
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScannedDetails.class);
    i.putExtra("CashCardImage",image_uri.getPath());
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: You have no path but an uri: a content scheme image_uri.toString().

Comment: `mPreviewIv.setImageURI(image_uri);`

Comment: @blackapp thanks for your response but  I have already that in my code when displaying the `ImageView`, but the thing is I think it needs to have a file format like  ` jpg/png` file but the question is how can I get the specfic path of the image since the result path I have now is just a number `174131`

Comment: You have no file system parh. You have an uri. And you will not try to get a file system path as you dont need it. You can use the uri.

Comment: @blackapps I don't have idea yet how can I get the image path based on the pick camera I've been created.

Comment: Of course not. And why would you? You dont need it as you have an uri. Third time i tell you. And you still did not tell why you want a path.

Comment: @blackapps sorry I just don't get it, I've already used my URI and yet it has a file path ,it does not recognize as an ImageView file because it does not have  `.jpg` format at the end of the image. I just want the file path to display in my `ImageView ` :(

Comment: You can display the picture taken by the Camera app with the code in my second comment. Using your uri. Now did you try that?

Comment: `String resultUri = extras.getString("CashCardImage")` What has that to do with your original `image_uri`?

Comment: @blackapps thanks for your response , Actually these code  `String resultUri = extras.getString("CashCardImage") ` I  tried to pass it to another activity through using an Intent the `image_uri ` you mention is the same value of that   `resultUri`

Comment: @blackapps I added the code above on how will I pass the data to another activity. The thing is the Uri is not the problem because when I tried another specific file with has format ` .jpg/png ` it displays the Image but the problem is on my path since it has no proper format :)

Comment: No the uries are not the same. Which you could easily check yourself looking at .toString() of both.

Comment: `i.putExtra("CashCardImage",image_uri.getPath())` Dont use .getPath() but .toString(). And if it finally works then look at my first comment again.

Comment: @blackapps Yes I forgot it should .toString yet I already done that since I provided only sample code but the thing is can I display an image with the use of this path ?  ` `/external/images/media/174131 `  don't know the exact path is. because when I tried using path `.jpg ` with it works well

Comment: Im waiting for you to tell that it works with .toString().

Comment: @blackapps Thank you! it works well now, I've been wondering lately because I used getPath() and it works but I tried againa it doesn't